# It is possible to split the dataset using kfolds with the same % of class using Julia 0.6?

Tags: split, dataset, julia, cross-validation

In Julia 0.6, is it possible to split the dataset using kfolds with the same % of classes? I mean if I have three classes blue, red and green, I´d like that each k-fold has the same observations' number (or very close) for each class. 
Like 20% for blue, 20% for green and 20% for red.

I´m using

```
folds = kfolds((Xtrain,Ttrain),k=7)
(xtreino1,ytreino1), (xvali1,yvali1) = folds[1]
```

but it does not return the same number of observations for each class.

Comment: Hi @Luísa, I've edited your text a bit, please have a look that it's still OK for you (especially, I've changed 6.0 to 0.6 -- 6.0 isn't out, yet :))

Comment: Do you mean [stratified cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation)? If so, there are certainly some existing implementations in learning packages.

Comment: yes @phg!!! but i didnt find that function in Julia, just kfolds function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what package you are using, but here is how you can achieve the desired result in plain Julia. I assume that vector `y` holds the target for your model:

```
using Random

function balanced_kfold(y::Vector, k::Integer)
    d = Dict{eltype(y), Vector{Int}}()
    folds = [Int[] for i in 1:k]
    for (i, v) in enumerate(y)
        push!(get!(d, v, Int[]), i)
    end
    for val in values(d)
        shuffle!(val)
        for (i, pos) in enumerate(val)
            push!(folds[mod1(i, k)], pos)
        end
    end
    folds
end
```

In this code `folds` will hold indices of entries of each fold. Notice, that in this code you might get a bit of unbalance in the sizes of folds as we try to balance both fold size and the distribution of target in each fold. Finally the code does not do any checking on `y` and `k` if they are valid.

EDIT: Now I see that you use Julia 0.6 - in this case all should work, but you do not need `using Random` statement as `shuffle!` should be loaded to global scope by default as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

The `MLBase` package has a [`StratifiedKfold`](https://mlbasejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crossval.html#StratifiedKfold) cross validation strategy:

```
julia> collect(StratifiedKfold([:a, :a, :a, :b, :b, :c, :c, :a, :b, :c], 3))
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1,2,4,6,8,9,10]
 [3,4,5,7,8,10]
 [1,2,3,5,6,7,9]
```

The returned arrays are supposed to be used as indices into the original data.

Comment: Hi, I dont understand. What those :a, :b, :c means?

Comment: That would be the training labels, based on which you would like the folds to be stratified.